# Is it proper to use an enumeration in this way?

Tags: kotlin, enums, enumeration

I'm making an android game in Kotlin and I'm wondering about the use of my enumeration.
It looks like this:

```kotlin
package com.example.makemoremeat.enumerations

import com.example.makemoremeat.R

enum class ProductionInformation(
    val initialNumber: Double,
    val initialCost: Double,
    val initialProduction: Double,
    val initialProductionTime: Double,
    val coefficientCostUp: Double,
    val imageProduction: Int
) {

    Chicken(1.0, 1.0, 0.1, 1.0, 1.13, R.drawable.production_work_in_progress),
    Beef(0.0, 7.0, 0.7, 2.0, 1.14, R.drawable.production_work_in_progress),
    Mutton(0.0, 49.0, 4.9, 4.0, 1.15, R.drawable.production_work_in_progress),
    Pork(0.0, 343.0, 34.3, 8.0, 1.16, R.drawable.production_work_in_progress),
    Rabbit(0.0, 2401.0, 240.1, 16.0, 1.17, R.drawable.production_work_in_progress),
    Horse(0.0, 16807.0, 1680.7, 32.0, 1.18, R.drawable.production_work_in_progress),
    Caribou(0.0, 117650.0, 11765.0, 64.0, 1.19, R.drawable.production_work_in_progress),
    Fish(0.0, 823540.0, 82354.0, 128.0, 1.20, R.drawable.production_work_in_progress),
    Dog(0.0, 5764800.0, 576480.0, 256.0, 1.21, R.drawable.production_work_in_progress),
    Elephant(0.0, 40354000.0, 4035400.0, 512.0, 1.22, R.drawable.production_work_in_progress),
    Bugs(0.0, 282480000.0, 28248000.0, 1024.0, 1.23, R.drawable.production_work_in_progress),
    Vegan(0.0, 1977300000.0, 197730000.0, 2048.01, 1.24, R.drawable.production_work_in_progress),
    Cultured(0.0, 13841000000.0, 1384100000.0, 4096.0, 1.25, R.drawable.production_work_in_progress)
}
```

And I use it this way:

```kotlin
class Production (
    private val game: Game,
    private val productionInformation: ProductionInformation
) {

    val image = productionInformation.imageProduction
    var numberPossessed = productionInformation.initialNumber
    var actualCost =
        productionInformation.initialCost * productionInformation.coefficientCostUp.pow(
            numberPossessed - 1
        )
    var actualProduction = productionInformation.initialProduction
    var actualProductionTime = productionInformation.initialProductionTime
[...]
```

Is it clean? Or else what would be the way to do in this case?
Inheritance with 13 classes extending Production would be better?
Thanks for your help !

Comment: It seems a sealed class would make more sense. Are you using it in enumeration somewhere?

Comment: I have never used a selaed class, is it better than a data class?

Comment: Sealed class is absolutely worse in this case for the reason I gave in my answer about inheritance and multiple classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance with multiple classes would definitely be worse! There is nothing here that necessitates different classes. None of these items need a unique property or function type.

It is an OK pattern in some cases. But if you don't really need to enforce a specific, finite set of possible items, a regular class, maybe `data` class, would be sufficient. For example, if you don't need to use `when` statements on it to treat each possible member differently, or be able to iterate all possible values, then making it an Enum class doesn't really buy you anything, and it limits where you can define instances. Your code above suggests no reason why this shouldn't just be a data class.

Since you have many entries, possibly it should be loaded from a resource like a JSON file pre-prepared database file.

Comment: Ok for the inheritance! I suspected it a little, however why put the data in a JSON and not directly in a data class?

Comment: JSON would still use a data class. When you have a very high amount of items, code simply isn’t always the easiest way to enter and compile your data. You might want it in a spreadsheet or database or something like that. For extremely high numbers of items, you also have to start considering the size of your compiled bytecode as a limiting factor as well.

Comment: I will follow your advice thank you for this perfectly constructed answer, I understand now!

Comment: Following what @Tenfour04 has said, I agree with the large aggregate data living outside of code in a separate file. That being said, it isn't always best case or feasible for the use case. I think what you have is fine for your situation, but if the data were any larger, or to be maintained with different changes over time, I would absolutely suggest moving to an external file such as json or csv.

Answer (score 1):

`enums` or "enumerated/enumaration data type", are widely used for selection constructs, use-cases where your logic would follow a certain path based on the `enum` you provide, consider the following, each described by a simple requirement

`Case 1`:

> Cold or Hot food, if the customer ordered a cold food, serve the customer with a jacket, if the customer orders a hot food, give him a bucket of ice

```
enum class FoodOrderType {
    COLD, HOT
}
```

somewhere in my code

```
val foodType = customer.getOrderedFoodType()

when (foodType) {
     FoodOrderType.COLD -> {
          // free jacket
      }
      FoodOrderType.HOT -> {
          // a bucket of ice
      }
}
```

`Case 2`:

> Depending on specific volume level of your car's current gasoline, make a decision whether to continue driving? get your wallet ready?, or look for a nearest gas station

```
enum class GasolineLevel {
    FULL, HALF, QUARTER
}
```

somewhere in my code

```
 val gasolineLevel = car.getGasolineLevel()

when (gasLevel) {
    GasolineLevel.FULL -> {
        // continue driving
    }
    GasolineLevel.HALF -> {
        // get your wallet ready
    }
    GasolineLevel.QUARTER -> {
        // look for the nearest station
    }
}
```

You can see that most of the examples above revolves around how your `code flow` will **decide** continuing, however in your question, it doesn't seem to warrant something for a "**decisional**" or "**conditional**" flow of code, its just an enum representing a series of characteristics `Inherited` by certain constructs.

Personally I see your code falling into an [Inheritance Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)), where your

- Chicken
- Beef
- Mutton
- Pork
- etc...

inherits their `characteristics` from `ProductionInformation` like

```
class Chicken : ProductInformation{ 
      ...
}
```

or

```
class Beef: ProductInformation{ 
      ...
}
```

or better yet, keeping the context intact you should suffix your class names based on its context like the following

```
class ChickenProduct : ProductInformation { 
      ...
}
```

or

```
class BeefProduct : ProductInformation{ 
      ...
}
```

There is nothing wrong with your code, but there are certain [OOP](https://www.interviewbit.com/blog/principles-of-oops/) principles that makes sense for certain use-cases.

Edit: I agree with Tenfour04, `composition` is the most ideal design strategy for your use-case, instead of a bloated package/directory full of similar classes with different names, [Prefer composition over inheritance](https://kt.academy/article/ek-composition)

Comment: Composition over inheritance. Unless different types of meat need to have different functions available, it would be better to make a MeatType enum and make it a property of the class rather than making a bunch of subclasses.

Comment: Yep I totally agree, I also hate inheritance especially in these types of situation, I'm just trying to simplify and let the OP ingest these OOP principles in a friendly pace, just focusing on his example , expounding what is wrong with it, and let him dig further about OOP principles.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, but since I don't plan to override any function I won't do any inheritance.

Comment: Definitely a good decision on your part!, nowadays, the problems of Inheritance are starting (or better yet already started) to outweigh the benefits it offered, so it's a good decision for you to NOT take that direction.